# Pass One Input Value Into Input Type Hidden Value When User Submits

Tags: php, javascript

I have a simple form as outlined in the code below.  I would like to append the value submitted in `rm_accounts` text box to the hidden `page_confirm` input value at the end of the URL.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Essentially, if the user enters `'123456'` in the rm_accounts textbox, I want value of page_confirm to be http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?rm_accounts=123456

```
<form name="signup" method="post" action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp" >

    <input type='text' name='rm_accounts' value='' />
    <input type="hidden" name="page_confirm" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?rm_accounts=">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" >

</form>
```

All help is very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you care if you use jquery or are you trying to just use straight javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Use Jquery `focusout` event to update hidden field value

When user enters 12345 and focus out of textbox or clicks submit(or anywhere) the below code get executed and update the value of hidden field.

```
$('input[type=text]').focusout(function(){
$('input[type=hidden]').val("http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?rm_accounts="+$('input[type=text]').val());
    console.log($('input[type=hidden]').val());
});
```

or in submit button click

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
  $('input[type=hidden]').val("http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?rm_accounts="+$('input[type=text]').val());
console.log($('input[type=hidden]').val());
});
```

Working JSFiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/mkamithkumar/qNdny/1/

Comment: I checked out the JSFiddle link and it makes sense with the alert but how do I get value into the "page_confirm" hidden input?

Essentially, I need the html to end up  like...

        <input type="hidden" name="page_confirm" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?rm_accounts=123456">

Comment: my jQuery skills are minimal so any hand holding is appreciated.

Comment: the value is already assigned to that hidden input..thats why it is showing up in alert..if the answer found useful please vote up and accept as answer to appreciate help

Comment: it looks like you are identifying the form elements by type. ex. 'input[type=text]' and 'input[type=hidden]'.

Is there a way to identify them by name?  I have several text inputs and hidden fields on the page.

Comment: see updated js fiddle to know how to select inputs and hidden fields by name http://jsfiddle.net/mkamithkumar/qNdny/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest you give your HTML some IDs like so:

```
<form id="signup" method="post" action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp" >
    <input type='text' name='rm_accounts' id='rm_accounts' value='' />
    <input type="hidden" name="page_confirm" id="page_confirm" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?rm_accounts=">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Then use some jQuery for your task:

```
$('#signup').submit(function(){
    var value = $('#rm_accounts').val();
    var page_confirm = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?rm_accounts='+value;

    $('#page_confirm').val(page_confirm);
});
```